# Search Customer By Name, Address, Contact Number, Etc

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, stored-procedures

I am stuck on a condition in searching customer depending upon values entered in name, address, contact number, paid amount etc.

If I enter name only then all customers matching `%name%` should be displayed below.
If I enter name and address then customers matching that criteria should be displayed.

I have Search fields

1) Name

2) Contact Number

3) Identity Type(ddl with options like PAN CARD, VOTING CARD, PASSPORT,etc)

4) Identity Number

5) Address

6) Amount Criteria(ddl with options Equal To, Less Than, Greater Than, Between)

7) Paid Amount(in case of Equal To, Less Than, Greater Than)

8) Minimum Amount(in case of Between)

9) Maximum Amount(in case of Between)

I tried like

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_search_customer", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if (txtCustomerName.Text != "" && txtContactNumber.Text != "" && cbIDProofType.Text != "" && txtIDNumber.Text != "" && txtAddress.Text != "" && txtAmountPaid.Text == "")
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = name;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_address", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = address;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_contact_number", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = contact_number;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_id_proof_type", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = id_proof_type;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = id_number;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@amount_paid", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 0;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@min_amount", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = min_amount;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@max_amount", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = max_amount;
                }
                else if (txtCustomerName.Text != "" && txtContactNumber.Text != "" && cbIDProofType.Text != "" && txtIDNumber.Text != "" && txtAddress.Text != "" && txtMinAmount.Text != "" && txtMaxAmount.Text != "")
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = name;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_address", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = address;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_contact_number", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = contact_number;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_id_proof_type", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = id_proof_type;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = id_number;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@amount_paid", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = amount_paid;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@min_amount", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 0;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@max_amount", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 0;
                }

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(DatTab);
            }

            this.customerBindingSource1.DataSource = DatTab;
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

and my stored procedure is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_search_customer]

@customer_name nvarchar(100),
@customer_address nvarchar(500),
@customer_contact_number nvarchar(50),
@customer_id_proof_type nvarchar(50),
@customer_id nvarchar(50),
@amount_paid int,
@min_amount_paid int,
@max_amount_paid int

as
begin
    select customer_number, customer_name, customer_address, customer_contact_number, customer_id_proof_type, customer_id, customer_vehicle_type, customer_vehicle_number, customer_room_number, customer_no_of_days_stay, customer_cost, check_in_date, number_of_adults, number_of_children
from Customer
where Customer.customer_name LIKE ''+'%'+@customer_name+'%'+''
    and Customer.customer_address LIKE ''+'%'+@customer_address+'%'+''
    AND Customer.customer_contact_number = @customer_contact_number
    AND Customer.customer_id_proof_type = @customer_id_proof_type
    AND Customer.customer_id = @customer_id
    AND Customer.customer_cost = @amount_paid
    AND Customer.customer_cost BETWEEN @min_amount_paid and @max_amount_paid
end
```

But results are not as expected.
If I use AND in every conditions then it shows me no record.
If I use OR in every conditions then it shows me all records.
Can you tell me How To Do this???

Did I have to use all possible combinations of these fields in if...else in my code???
Or is there any way so that this task can be done easily?

Comment: If search is by `name` then other `variables` will be null right

Comment: Yes. If I enter only `name` then other will be null. But If I have multiple records matching that `name` then I will go for `contact_number` or `address` or any other field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass NULL for values that are not given:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{ 
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{ 
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@customer_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = name;
}
```

Then check for NULL in your stored procedure:

```
where (Customer.customer_name LIKE ''+'%'+@customer_name+'%'+'' or @customer_name is null)
and (Customer.customer_address LIKE ''+'%'+@customer_address+'%'+'' or @customer_address is null)
...
```

Comment: **Thorsten Kettner** Thank You. This did exactly what I want. Thank You So much

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your stored procedure

```
BEGIN
    SELECT customer_number, customer_name, customer_address, customer_contact_number, customer_id_proof_type, customer_id, customer_vehicle_type, customer_vehicle_number, customer_room_number, customer_no_of_days_stay, customer_cost, check_in_date, number_of_adults, number_of_children
from Customer
where   Customer.customer_contact_number = @customer_contact_number
    AND Customer.customer_id_proof_type = @customer_id_proof_type
    AND Customer.customer_id = @customer_id
    AND Customer.customer_cost = @amount_paid
    AND Customer.customer_cost BETWEEN @min_amount_paid 
    AND @max_amount_paid
    OR Customer.customer_name LIKE ''+'%'+@customer_name+'%'+''
    OR Customer.customer_address LIKE ''+'%'+@customer_address+'%'+''
END
```

The disadvantage is that even if one entry is wrong, then you might nit get exact results.

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean parameter for each variable in where clause:

`(name LIKE @name AND @p1 = 1 OR @p1 = 0) AND (contactno LIKE @contactno AND @p2 = 1 OR @p2 = 0) AND ...` and so on.

If you are using a variable to search, set the parameter corresponding to it to `true`, if not then `false`.

Advantages:

1. This way you just have to write only a single command for any type of searches.
2. You don't have to worry about null values.

Comment: Null value (from Thorsten answer) used exactly for the same purpose as your suggested boolean parameter. Advantage - you don't need to write 10 more parameters for stored procedure